# C++ Reference to local variable vs reference to parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference

I am writing my own htonl, htons, ntohl, and ntohs functions, and I'm getting behavior I don't understand. The code below works as expected:

```
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort)
{
    uint16_t netshort = 0;
    uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) (&netshort);

    p[0] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    p[1] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0x00FF) >> 0);

    return netshort;
}

uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort)
{
    uint16_t hostshort = 0;
    uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) netshort;


    hostshort |= ((uint16_t)p[0]) << 8;
    hostshort |= ((uint16_t)p[1]) << 0;


    return hostshort;
}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work at all:

```
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort)
{
    uint16_t netshort = 0;
    uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) netshort;

    p[0] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    p[1] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0x00FF) >> 0);

    return netshort;
}

uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort)
{
    uint16_t hostshort = 0;
    uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) (&netshort);


    hostshort |= ((uint16_t)p[0]) << 8;
    hostshort |= ((uint16_t)p[1]) << 0;


    return hostshort;
}
```

When I remove the & from netshort in htons, it returns all zeroes, and when I add it in ntohs, it returns garbage. Can someone please explain how they're being handled differently? My understanding was that both cases should be returning a pointer to the start of the data in memory, but they're obviously being handled differently. Is there something implicit happening with the parameter?

Comment: It looks like you're casting a value directly to a pointer without taking the address. The result is undefined. So sometimes it might work by accident.

Comment: uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) (&netshort); should be correct however there might be a problem with your ntohs code other than this if it is returning garbage.

Comment: The code is not compilable in the current form, voting to close.

Comment: @SergeyA It compiles for me, albeit with warnings.

Comment: @Ramon, yes, my bad. I am used to warnings as errors, forgot that some of them are just warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint16_t netshort = 0;
uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) netshort;
```

This says, take the value of netshort (which is `0`), and interpret that as a `uint8_t*` pointer. In this case, that would be null.

This means that the following lines, assigning something to that pointer are undefined.

```
p[0] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0xFF00) >> 8);
p[1] = (uint8_t)((hostshort & 0x00FF) >> 0);
```

You need to take the address of the local.

```
uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) &netshort;
```

Comment: That should not even compile.

Comment: @SergeyA It may be useful to explain why it "should not even compile".

Comment: Like I said, I am too used to warnings as errors, and I forgot some of them are warnings without that.

Comment: @cocarin That makes sense; can you explain why the opposite is true for the ntohs function, though? My understanding was the parameter was being passed by value, so it would have the same problem, but it only works when I don't cast the reference.